# alphanumeric key for sorted not working on python 3.0

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Below piece of code works on Python2.7 but fails on Python 3.0 with:

```
sorted_tuples = sorted(s, key=lambda result: try_numeric(result[0]))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Code:

```
s = [['4', 'lookalike_trainer', '48 sheets', '12 sheets'], ['lookalike_trainer', '4 sheets', '48 sheets', '12 sheets'], ['40', '4 sheets', '48 sheets', '12 sheets']]

def try_numeric(value):

   try:

      return int(value, 10)

   except ValueError:

       return value


sorted_tuples = sorted(s, key=lambda result: try_numeric(result[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that sometimes `try_numeric` returns an integer value and sometimes it returns a string value. Is `4 > "foo"`? How do you compare these? The issue is that Python can't, so when it tries to compare them it will fail. Python 2 supported this type of comparison but that was removed in Python 3.